# WPF usercontrol issue

Tags: wpf

I have WPF usercontrol that is binded to some data, when I run the usercontrol it shows the data, but when I place the usercontrol on WPF window it shows blank with no data!

What is the correct way to add binded usercontrol to WPF window?

Comment: Elaborate your question and put some code..

Answer (score 4):

You need to define an xlmns which refers to your application and namespace, something like

```
xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:MyApp.View"
```

then you can reference your UserControl with

```
<vw:MyControl DataContext="{Binding MyData}" />
```

It sounds as if you might be doing it all apart from the binding - run your app and look in the Ouput window to see if there are binding errors.

Comment: +1 amaca - Also remember to use ObservableCollection<MyData> if required.